# Variable declarations are definitions?

Tags: c++

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) states:

> Every declaration is a definition, except for the following:

and then I do not see non-static(local) variables on the list of exceptions. However, I get why that static variables are considered as defined when declared since they are initialized to zero. BUT non-static variables are indeterminate, so are those non-static variables considered as being defined when being declared - as with static variables?

Example:

```
int x; // zero
int y = 0; // also zero

void foo() {
    static int x; // also zero
}
```

So here all the `x` and `y` are initialized to zero and therefore I think I get it if those declarations are considered as definitions.

But

```
void foo() {
    int x;
    printf("%d", x); // the compiler is free to crash here
}
```

Is the declaration of `x` also a definition, I mean this declaration does not really initialized to anything, right?

In fact, I have always thought that there was a pretty obvious difference between declarations and definitions, like `int x;`, `class X;` vs. `int x = 2` and `class X {};`.

Also, if it is true that the declarations static variables also are definitions, why are static class members included in the exception list and not static variables that are not a member of a class?

Comment: definition is different thing than initialization, it is not clear why you linked them together

Comment: @Slava well okay then. However, I do not think that ruin the content of my qeustions because I still do not know whether the declarations non-static variables(not really sure about static) are definitions too? Btw. I totally forgot that definitions and initializations aren't the same thing.. I am still confused though

Comment: Declaration of local variables is always definition, for non local variables you can make declaration not definition by using keyword `extern` explicitly.

Comment: Plus, I do not get how declarations are definitions? As I implied in the post.

Comment: @Slava thanks. But exactly why is that? Are static variables defined when declared too then?

Comment: "how declarations are definitions?" if you write `int x;` that is declaration and definition of variable `x` of type `int`. What is not clear?

Comment: @Slava yeah okay I got you now. I think my confusion came a lot from when I mixed up definitions and initializations. One thing more though: I still do not get why static data members aren't defined then when declared in a class definition since static variables are defined by their declaration? I mean, static data members are included in the exception list

Comment: Though initialization sometimes turns a declaration into a definition, they are actually separate constructs. Read 3.1 Declarations and definitions (2) in this c++ standard (early) draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf. Maybe things get clearer then.

Comment: @NeiLee "I still do not get why static data members aren't defined then when declared in a class definition" because it is common to put class declaration in a header file, so that declaration is visible in every translation unit which includes this  header. But static data member must be defined only once.